# Idris proof with RHS as function definition

Tags: math, proof, idris

I'm trying to get my head around some simple proofs by trying to prove the equivalence of a computational method of computing triangular numbers to the closed form of them. So far, all I've managed to achieve is this:

```
total 
tn_eval : (n : Nat) -> Nat
tn_eval Z = Z
tn_eval (S k)  = (S k) + tn_eval k

total 
tn_closed : (n: Nat) -> Nat
tn_closed Z = Z
tn_closed (S k) = div ((S k) * ((S k) - 1)) 2

total 
tn_closed_proof : (n : Nat) -> (tn_closed n) = (tn_eval n)
tn_closed_proof Z = ?strange_hole
tn_closed_proof (S k) = ?more_difficult_hole
```

However, I've got stuck as to what the possible definition of `?strange_hole` should be. Inspecting the type gives:

```
Idris: Type of strange_hole
--------------------------------------
strange_hole : tn_closed 0 = 0
```

Which (as I understand it) is literally the definition of `tn_closed Z`, so, this should be provable simply using `Refl`, as `tn_closed 0` is definitionally equivalent to `0`.

However, this isn't right, as when I try this, I get a type error:

```
When checking right hand side of tn_closed_proof with expected type
        tn_closed 0 = tn_eval 0

Type mismatch between
        0 = 0 (Type of Refl)
and
        tn_closed 0 = 0 (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                0
        and
                tn_closed 0
```

Along with the totality warning:

```
Arith.tn_closed is possibly not total due to: Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Integral
```

I feel like the latter might be the reason for the former, but aside from that I'm totally stuck! As I understood it, `tn_closed 0` and `0` were *by definition* equivalent, so any proof requiring `tn_closed 0 = 0` should be trivial, or provable with `Refl`, but it would seem that I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I asked the question, I managed to solve it!

As far as I understand it, the issue lay in the definition of `tn_closed`, specifically:

```
tn_closed (S k) = div ((S k) * ((S k) - 1)) 2
```

This definition meant that Idris (for some reason) didn't understand that the division was total. Replacing this definition with the following:

```
tn_closed (S k) = divNatNZ ((S k) * ((S k) - 1)) 2 SIsNotZ
```

Gave the much more approachable hole:

```
Idris: Type of hole
--------------------------------------
hole : 0 = 0
```

This is fairly simple to solve with Refl!

Comment: Integral Nat uses divNat as its implementation, and divNat is not total since it is only defined for divisors which are greater zero. hence tn_closed is by definition not total and you have been warned about that. Idris does not do reasoning, e.g. it will not do the math for you that 2 is greater 0, if you want this, you were right to use divNatNZ which requires you to prove that 2 is not 0.